# what ways can I make one new line in a post?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting

what ways can I make one new line in a post?

And what is the sense in the fact that pushing enter and starting a new line, doesn't create a new line when the question or I guess answer is submitted?

Suppose I write 
a  b c 
I just want a b and c to be on adjacent lines. But they come up as a b c

And why is it that when I highlight something and press "Code" I get the backquote thing appear around it, but when I just click code, it lets me enter what it calls "code" which no doubt needn't be.. But it doesn't include hte backquote.. so how would it even know what i'm typing is to be formatted as code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you click on the `?` at the top right of the editing box, it leads you to the [markdown editing help page](https://meta.superuser.com/editing-help). This page is far from complete, but does mention

> End a line with two spaces to add a 
>  linebreak:

You can also use the `<br>` HTML tag (or `<br/>`) directly.

Two newlines make a paragraph break, a newline preceded by two spaces is a line break, and there are a few other cases where newlines have a special meaning, but by default, a newline is a whitespace character like any other, and a sequence of whitespace is rendered as a space.

There are two ways to enter code (almost all characters are rendered literally, and in a teletype font): `` `between backquotes` `` (⇒ `between backquotes`) and in a paragraph indented four spaces. You can also get a teletype font without suppressing special characters as `<code>foo</code>` (⇒ `foo`).

Answer (score 3):

use `<br />`

A 
 B 
 C

> so how would it even know what i'm typing is to be formatted as code

It doesn't using backticks makes it apply syntax formatting. Else prefixing 4 spaces does the same.

```
like so
```

This is [how I](https://meta.superuser.com/revisions/5db5f237-9391-481d-a8e9-6c448325c766/view-source) entered this post

Comment: two spaces at end of line is mentioned in the editing sidebar and the editing help, and is always preferred (not to mention less typing) compared to `<br>`

Comment: @Gilles @Satya This does<br><br>not work for me, **[look](http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/758721?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1310146661&Signature=nkA1mSuJAteLoifBBf5%2BEIuXkJU%3D)**

Comment: @Gilles @Satya Also how to underline text?

Comment: @Boris_yo screenshot link is broken. ProTip: Don't hotlink AWS links, they expire after certain about time.

Comment: @Sathya Expire links or images?

Comment: @Boris_yo both.

Comment: Well as you can see from my comment after Jeff Atwood i could not break lines. <br> <br /?>

Comment: @Boris_yo still works fine. http://i.imgur.com/55rbM.png

Comment: HTML tags aren't supported in Comments @Boris_yo